# Python img error

Tags: python, flask-admin

Выбивает вот такую вот ошибку:

```
(venv) D:\projectprobe\projectflask\site>python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 263, in <module>
    class ImageView(sqla.ModelView):
  File "app.py", line 278, in ImageView
    'path': form.ImageUploadField('Image',
AttributeError: module 'wtforms.form' has no attribute 'ImageUploadField'
```

Использую фласк-админ, не могу понять как правильно сделать так, чтобы в панели админа отображался баттон для загрузки картинок! Помогите пожалуйста.

```
    import os
    import os.path as op
    from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for
    from jinja2 import Markup
    from flask import Flask, Blueprint, render_template, url_for, redirect, request, session, flash, abort
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask_admin import helpers, expose, form
    from flask_admin import helpers as admin_helpers
    import flask_admin as admin
    import flask_login as login
    from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
    from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, UserMixin, RoleMixin, current_user
    from wtforms import form, StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, validators, fields
    from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

    # Create application
    app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='files')

    app.config['DATABASE_FILE'] = 'sample_db.sqlite'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + app.config['DATABASE_FILE']
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisissecret'

    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    # Create directory for file fields to use
    file_path = op.join(op.dirname(__file__), 'static/images/menu-product')
    try:
        os.mkdir(file_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    # Define models
    roles_users = db.Table(
        'roles_users',
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
        db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
    )


    class Role(RoleMixin, db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
        description = db.Column(db.String(255))

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name


    # Create models
    class File(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))
        path = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name


    class Image(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))
        path = db.Column(db.Unicode(128))

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name


    class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        login = db.Column(db.String(255))
        email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
        password = db.Column(db.String(100))
        active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
        registered_on = db.Column('registered_on', db.DateTime)
        roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                                backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

        # Flask-Login integration
        def is_authenticated(self):
            return True

        def is_active(self):
            return True

        def is_anonymous(self):
            return False

        def get_id(self):
            return self.id

        # Required for administrative interface
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.login

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<User %r>' % self.login

        def __str__(self):
            return self.email
            # Setup Flask-Security


    user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
    security = Security(app, user_datastore)


    # Define login and registration forms (for flask-login)
    class LoginForm(form.Form):
        user_message = 'Mailing address should be no more than 60 characters'
        user_required = 'Please enter your login.'
        pass_message = 'Password should be no more than 50 characters'
        pass_required = 'Please enter your password.'

        login = fields.StringField('Username', validators=[validators.Length(message=user_message, max=60),
                                                           validators.required(user_required)])
        password = fields.PasswordField('Password', validators=[validators.Length(message=pass_message, max=50),
                                                                validators.required(pass_required)])

        def get_user(self):
            return db.session.query(User).filter_by(login=self.login.data).first()

        def validate_login(self, field):
            user = self.get_user()

            if user is None:
                raise validators.ValidationError('Invalid user')

            # we're comparing the plaintext pw with the the hash from the db
            if not check_password_hash(user.password, self.password.data):
                # to compare plain text passwords use
                # if user.password != self.password.data:
                raise validators.ValidationError('Invalid password')


    class RegistrationForm(form.Form):
        username_message = 'The name must be at least 4 letters and no more than 25 characters'
        username_required = 'Please enter your login.'
        email_address_message = 'Mailing address should be no more than 60 characters'
        email_address_required = 'Please enter your email address.'
        password_message = 'Passwords must match'

        login = fields.StringField('Username', validators=[validators.Length(message=username_message, min=4, max=25),
                                                           validators.required(username_required)])
        email = fields.StringField('Email', validators=[validators.Length(message=email_address_message, max=60),
                                                        validators.required(email_address_required)])
        password = fields.PasswordField('Password', validators=[validators.required(password_message),
                                                                validators.EqualTo('confirm',
                                                                                   message='Passwords must match')])
        confirm = fields.PasswordField('Repeat Password')

        def validate_login(self, field):
            if db.session.query(User).filter_by(login=self.login.data).count() > 0:
                raise validators.ValidationError('Duplicate username')
            if db.session.query(User).filter_by(email=self.email.data).count() > 0:
                raise validators.ValidationError('Duplicate email')


    # Initialize flask-login
    def init_login():
        login_manager = login.LoginManager()
        login_manager.init_app(app)

        # Create user loader function
        @login_manager.user_loader
        def load_user(user_id):
            return db.session.query(User).get(user_id)


    # Create customized model view class
    class MyModelView(sqla.ModelView):
        def is_accessible(self):
            if not current_user.is_active or not current_user.is_authenticated:
                return False

            if current_user.has_role('superuser'):
                return True

            return False

        def _handle_view(self, name, **kwargs):
            """
            Override builtin _handle_view in order to redirect users when a view is not accessible.
            """
            if not self.is_accessible():
                if current_user.is_authenticated:
                    # permission denied
                    abort(403)
                else:
                    # login
                    return redirect(url_for('admin.login_view', next=request.url))


    class MyMasterIndexView(sqla.ModelView):
        def is_accessible(self):
            if not current_user.is_active or not current_user.is_authenticated:
                return False

            if current_user.has_role('user'):
                return True

            return False

        def _handle_view(self, name, **kwargs):
            """
            Override builtin _handle_view in order to redirect users when a view is not accessible.
            """
            if not self.is_accessible():
                if current_user.is_authenticated:
                    # permission denied
                    abort(403)
                else:
                    # login
                    return redirect(url_for('admin.login_view', next=request.url))

    # Delete hooks for models, delete files if models are getting deleted
    @listens_for(File, 'after_delete')
    def del_file(mapper, connection, target):
        if target.path:
            try:
                os.remove(op.join(file_path, target.path))
            except OSError:
                # Don't care if was not deleted because it does not exist
                pass

    @listens_for(Image, 'after_delete')
    def del_image(mapper, connection, target):
        if target.path:
            # Delete image
            try:
                os.remove(op.join(file_path, target.path))
            except OSError:
                pass

            # Delete thumbnail
            try:
                os.remove(op.join(file_path,
                                  form.thumbgen_filename(target.path)))
            except OSError:
                pass

    # Administrative views
    '''
    class FileView(sqla.ModelView):
        # Override form field to use Flask-Admin FileUploadField
        form_overrides = {
            'path': form.FileUploadField
        }

        # Pass additional parameters to 'path' to FileUploadField constructor
        form_args = {
            'path': {
                'label': 'File',
                'base_path': file_path,
                'allow_overwrite': False
            }
        }
    '''


    class ImageView(sqla.ModelView):
        def _list_thumbnail(view, context, model, name):
            if not model.path:
                return ''

            return Markup('<img src="%s">' % url_for('static',
                                                     filename=form.thumbgen_filename(model.path)))

        column_formatters = {
            'path': _list_thumbnail
        }

        # Alternative way to contribute field is to override it completely.
        # In this case, Flask-Admin won't attempt to merge various parameters for the field.
        form_extra_fields = {
            'path': form.ImageUploadField('Image',
                                          base_path=file_path,
                                          thumbnail_size=(100, 100, True))
        }



    # Create customized index view class that handles login & registration
    class MyAdminIndexView(admin.AdminIndexView):
        @expose('/')
        def index(self):
            if not login.current_user.is_authenticated:
                return redirect(url_for('.login_view'))
            return super(MyAdminIndexView, self).index()

        @expose('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
        def login_view(self):
            # handle user login
            form = LoginForm(request.form)
            if helpers.validate_form_on_submit(form):
                user = form.get_user()
                login.login_user(user)

            if login.current_user.is_authenticated:
                return redirect(url_for('.index'))
            link = '<p>Don\'t have an account? <a href="' + url_for('.register_view') + '">Click here to register.</a></p>'
            self._template_args['form'] = form
            self._template_args['link'] = link
            return super(MyAdminIndexView, self).index()

        @expose('/register/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
        def register_view(self):
            form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
            if helpers.validate_form_on_submit(form):
                user = User()

                form.populate_obj(user)
                # we hash the users password to avoid saving it as plaintext in the db,
                # remove to use plain text:
                user.password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data)

                db.session.add(user)
                db.session.commit()

                login.login_user(user)
                return redirect(url_for('.index'))
            link = '<p>Already have an account? <a href="' + url_for('.login_view') + '">Click here to log in.</a></p>'
            self._template_args['form'] = form
            self._template_args['link'] = link
            return super(MyAdminIndexView, self).index()

        @expose('/logout/')
        def logout_view(self):
            login.logout_user()
            return redirect(url_for('.index'))


    # Flask views
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')


    # Initialize flask-login
    init_login()

    # Create admin
    admin = admin.Admin(app, index_view=MyAdminIndexView(), base_template='my_master.html')

    # Add view
    admin.add_view(MyModelView(User, db.session))
    admin.add_view(MyModelView(Role, db.session))
    #admin.add_view(FileView(File, db.session))
    admin.add_view(ImageView(Image, db.session, name='Order'))


    # define a context processor for merging flask-admin's template context into the
    # flask-security views.
    @security.context_processor
    def security_context_processor():
        return dict(
            admin_base_template=admin.base_template,
            admin_view=admin.index_view,
            h=admin_helpers,
            get_url=url_for
        )


    def build_sample_db():
        """
        Populate a small db with some example entries.
        """

        db.create_all()

        with app.app_context():
            user_role = Role(name='user')
            super_user_role = Role(name='superuser')
            db.session.add(user_role)
            db.session.add(super_user_role)
            db.session.commit()

            test_user = user_datastore.create_user(
                login='Admin',
                email='admin',
                password=generate_password_hash('admin'),
                roles=[super_user_role]
            )
            db.session.add(test_user)
            db.session.commit()

        return


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        # Build a sample db on the fly, if one does not exist yet.
        app_dir = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        database_path = os.path.join(app_dir, app.config['DATABASE_FILE'])
        if not os.path.exists(database_path):
            build_sample_db()

        # Start app
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что в строке 7 импортируется модуль с названием form из пакета flask_admin, а затем в строке 14 импортируется модуль form из пакета wtforms он переопределяет ранее импортированный модуль из пакета flask_admin.